# iOS, Low priority thread before a view controller segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I have two view controllers: `ViewControllerA` & `ViewControllerB`

If I create a low priority thread on `ViewControllerA` then immediately afterwards trigger a segue to `ViewControllerB` does that thread have to finish before the segue will start?

This is the type of behavior I am seeing in my app, I was just wondering if this is what could be the cause.

Comment: Update your question with relevant code so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: You can design it so it will wait. You can design it so it won't wait. It all depends upon how you implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

The low-priority thread doesn't **have to** finish before the segue, but it probably starts its work right away. Even if you do the segue immediately after you set up the thread, there is probably lots of time in between for the computer to start working on the thread before the segue happens.

Once the thread starts some work - even if it's low priority - it is going to finish it. It does not pause in the middle of a task, even for higher priority work. The priority system only governs which task is picked next - it will not switch between half-finished tasks based on priority.

And besides that, iOS devices all have at least 2 cores. Even if the segue starts before the low-priority work does, it's likely that the low priority work will start on another core at nearly the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Create your low priority thread in

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

in your view controller. You do your validation there, and if it´s OK then return YES; if it´s not the return NO; and the prepareForSegue is not call.